# From NText To XML Data Type Conversion

Tags: sql-server

I updated the column's datatype from `NTEXT` to `XML`; it worked for me, but the issue is that one of the node's attribute's position has changed.

Before (with `NTEXT`):

```
<Message version="010" release="006" mlns="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging">
```

After (with `XML`)

```
<Message xmlns="http://www.surescripts.com/messaging" version="010" release="006">
```

Comment: The namespace is always at the beginning so when converting a string it will move the namespace to the front. I have to ask though, why is this an issue?

Comment: The `XML` type treats namespace declarations (`xmlns`) specially and will always present these before "regular" attributes. If you need a value that round-trips exactly, including all formatting, use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. More likely, the fact that the order changed is not actually a problem -- if the data is treated as XML, the results will be the same because the order of namespace declarations is irrelevant. (Assuming `mlns` is actually a typo for `xmlns`.)

Comment: thanks for feedback.In my case HASH is generated and and after type conversion that hash is not valid so far.

Comment: The normal solution for that is to hash only [canonical XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_XML), where attributes are sorted alphabetically and other semantically irrelevant variations are reduced to a single form. SQL Server implements no form of canonicalization, however. If you need to hash the textual value of the input exactly as-is, you can't use the `XML` type to store the input, as it can't be expected to maintain the text. You should still not use `NTEXT`, as that has been deprecated for a long time. Use `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and cast to `XML` only where needed.